# How to update tableView cell height

Tags: ios, swift

After press button I want to update my cell height so atm I'm used this closure and call him in my button method, but is not working ):

my viewDidLoad():

```
 tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 238.0
 tableView.rowHeight = 238.0
```

my closure which try to change cell height after press a button

```
cellClosureHeight = { [weak self] in
            self?.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self?.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 118.0
            self?.tableView.rowHeight = 118.0
            self?.tableView.endUpdates()
        }
```

my cell init

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            switch productCells[indexPath.row] {
            case .popCorn(let viewModel):
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
                    withIdentifier: TableViewCells.popCornOrder.identifier,
                    for: indexPath
                    ) as! ProductTableViewCell

                cell.set(viewModel: viewModel)

                return cell

            case .barWater(let viewModel):
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
                    withIdentifier: TableViewCells.barWaterOrder.identifier,
                    for: indexPath
                    ) as! ProductTableViewCell

                cell.set(viewModel: viewModel)

                return cell
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without animate

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

animate

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
let indexPaths = [IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)] //the cells you want to update
tableView.reloadRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Does you change the cell height?

Comment: yea, I try to change

Comment: I test your code, it work well.  Are there some extensions affect the tableView updates.

Comment: nope, maybe its not working for me cuz I don't take the right `let indexPaths = [IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)]`?

Answer (score 0):

> tableView.reloadData()

after making changes in table you should have to reload the table to reflect the new changes that you have applied.

Comment: in my case I don't needed `tableView.reloadData()` cuz `tableView.beginUpdates() `and `tableView.endUpdates()` is better

Comment: yea, thanks mate, but unfortunately this func not working for me too :/

Comment: yes you are right at your point but i just suggesting it when you have to make the change that reflects on the whole table you should go with reloading or when you have some animation to play with go with begin and end Updates